# How to get state of child component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have Main Component file and use in another child component.
I have to get state of the child component.

Ex :- Home (Parent)
    - Form (Child) component i have been set the value of any text box in state. So ho can i get the state value of Form component into the main component.

Comment: You can use state lifting

Comment: Please show us your code. In React data should always flow down in the component tree. So instead of passing state up to the parent you should move your state to the parent and pass the data down to the child as props. Also see [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the react docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally in React (and React-Native) information is passed down from the parent component to its children. However if you need to change something in the parent component's state based on the child-component's state, you can pass a function to the child that does just that.

For example:

```
// Inside Parent Component
openModalFromParent() {
  this.setState({ modalOpened: true });
};

// Passing Function to Child
<ChildComponent openModal={ this.openModalFromParent } />

// Inside Child Component
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.props.openModal() } />
```

In this example the button in the child component would trigger a function that alters the state of the parent component - hope this helps!

Comment: i do something like this (y)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the function as a prop to the child component

```
//Parent Component
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          username: '',
          password: '',
        };

        this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      _handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      }

      render(){   
         return(){
             <Form valueChange={this._handleChange} />
         }
      }       
}

//Child Component    
export default class Form extends Component {
render(){
   return(){
     <div>
       <input type="email" name="username" onChange={(e) => this.props.valueChange()} value={username}/>
        <input type="password" name="password" onChange={(e) => this.props.valueChange()} value={password}/>
    </div>
  }     
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, your state can only flow down from the parent to the children.
What you should do is move the state from the child to the parent and then pass the state to the child as props.

Try reading this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: You're right. But I would add that this is a best-practice not just in React, children should know nothing about their parents.